# How to unstake ALL my EOS from EOS Voter Greymass

Tags: nodeos

I have 8 EOS still staked on Voter Greymass. 6 EOS Staked to CPU and 2 to Bandwidth. I want to unstake all my EOS and transfer them to my Ledger key.
Unfortunately every time I try to do this I get the error message pasted below, even if I try to unstake just 1 or 2 EOS at a time.
Please, could anyone help me?
Thanks a lot

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have enough resourcecs staked to complete the action of unstaking your resources.

There are some services (such as bloks.io) that offer 5 free transactions per day, you can use them to unstake and transfer your funds